# Opposite of "Concerto Grosso"?

Tags: composition

Sounds like a joke, but in fact *asking for a friend* who is not a musician.  Was there ever a "Concerto Piccolo" or some such contrast to the "Concerto Grosso" format?

Comment: When you say "opposite," what aspect of the concerto grosso do you have in mind? Wikipedia says the concerto grosso is "a form of baroque music in which the musical material is passed between a small group of soloists (the concertino) and full orchestra (the ripieno or concerto grosso). ... This is in contrast to the solo concerto which features a single solo instrument with the melody line, accompanied by the orchestra." Is solo concerto what you're looking for? Without this clarification, I think you're going to get lots of answers focusing on different aspects of the concerto grosso.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the term *concerto grosso* the *grosso* refers to the full orchestra, the *ripieno.* The orchestra is contrasted with a *group* of soloists. That group is called the *concertino.*

That contrasts with the term *solo concerto* or just plain *concerto* where there is only a single soloist.

In either case the full orchestra is called the *ripieno.*

It's kind of tricky terminology. *Grosso* is about the orchestra, but the full terms *concerto grosso* and *solo concerto* contrast the size of the solo(ists.)

The *meaningful* opposite of *concerto grosso* is simply *solo concerto* in the sense that the meaningful part is the size of the solo group.

*Concerto grosso* and *concertino* are opposite *within* the meaning of concerto grosso in that the large orchestra is contrasted against the concertino, the two groups sort of oppose each other.

There really isn't an *opposite* with this - like darkness is the opposite of light - so I wouldn't get hung up on one single notion of 'opposite.'

Answer (score 5):

The [first reference given in wikpedia](http://www.lcsproductions.net/MusicHistory/MusHistRev/Articles/BarConGrsso.html) has it concise:

> "Concerto grosso" originally signified the "large consort," that is, the orchestra, as opposed to the "concertino" or "little consort," the group of solo instruments.  Later, the term "concerto grosso" was applied to the composition which used these opposed groups.

The instrumentally smaller precursor was the *trio sonata*.

That being said, the question is mostly caused by the strange name (if the repertoire is meant.) It is not very different from asking for the opposite of a *symphony*. (Chamber music?)

Answer (score 3):

Linguistically, the opposite of a Concerto Grosso would be a [Concertino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concertino_(composition)). Wikipedia defines it as

> Concertino is the diminutive of concerto, thus literally a small or short concerto.

...and lists dozens of examples.

In terms of the structure and lineup of a concerto grosso, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concerto_grosso) notes

> The concerto grosso [...] is a form of baroque music in which the musical material is passed between a small group of soloists (the concertino) and full orchestra (the ripieno or concerto grosso). **This is in contrast to the solo concerto** which features a single solo instrument with the melody line, accompanied by the orchestra.